# Operator overloading enum class

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the `&` operator of an enum class, but I'm getting this compiler error: error: no match for 'operator&=' (operand types are 'int' and 'Numbers'). Any ideas about this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class Numbers : int
{
    zero                    = 0, 
    one                     = 0x01,
    two                     = 0x02
};

inline int operator &(int a, Numbers b)
{
    return ((a) & static_cast<int>(b));
}

int main() {
    int a=1;
    a&=Numbers::one;
    cout << a ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is telling exactly what's wrong. You didn't overload `&=`.

Despite the expected semantics, `&=` doesn't automatically expand to `a = a & Numbers::one;`

If you want to have both, the canonical way is to usually implement `op` in terms of `op=`. So your original function is adjusted as follows:

```
inline int& operator &=(int& a, Numbers b)
{ // Note the pass by reference
    return (a &= static_cast<int>(b));
}
```

And the new one uses it:

```
inline int operator &(int a, Numbers b)
{ // Note the pass by value
    return (a &= b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice question but your tremendously helpful compiler diagnostic tells you everything you need to know.

You are missing the *bitwise AND assignment operator" : `operator&=`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are overloading the operator `&`. But then you are using the operator `&=` which is a different one. Overload that too and you'll be fine.